# Most efficient way to convert numpy array to dict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([10, 20, 30])
```

I need to create a list of dicts:

```
res = 
[{"a": 1, "b": 10},
 {"a": 2, "b": 20},
 {"a": 3, "b": 30}]
```

in most optimal way, without iterating through the whole array.

The obvious solution

```
res = [{"a": a_el, "b": b_el} for a_el, b_el in zip(a, b)]
```

takes too much time if a and b has a lot of values inside

Comment: On what order of magnitude is "a lot of values"

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? How can you use all of the values if you don't iterate through all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to also importing pandas, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
res = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

which gives the desired `res`:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 2, 'b': 20}, {'a': 3, 'b': 30}]
```

<strike>Depending on the size of your arrays, this might not be worth it.</strike> It appears this isn't worth it regardless of the size of your arrays, but I'm going to keep this answer for its educational value, and will update it to compare the runtimes of methods that other people suggest.

---

Timing both approaches, my computer shows the `zip` approach is always faster than the pandas approach, so disregard the previous part of this answer.

[image: plot]

Ranking (fastest to slowest)

1. Plain old `zip`
2. [0x0fba's `np.col_stack`](/a/74705584/843953)
3. [My approach -- create a dataframe and `df.to_dict`](/a/74705433/843953)
   = [crashMOGWAI's numba approach](/a/74705540/843953) (time for first function call is skewed by compilation time)

```
import timeit
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f_zip(a, b):
    return [{"a": ai, "b": bi} for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]

def f_pd(a, b):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
    return df.to_dict(orient='records')

def f_col_stack(a, b):
    return [{"a": a, "b": b} for a, b in np.column_stack((a,b))]

@jit
def f_numba(a, b):
    return [{"a": a_el, "b": b_el} for a_el, b_el in zip(a, b)]


funcs = [f_zip, f_pd, f_col_stack, f_numba]
sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000]
times = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs)))

N = 20

for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
    a = np.random.random((s,))
    b = np.random.random((s,))
    for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
        times[i, j] = timeit.timeit("f(a, b)", globals=globals(), number=N) / N
        print(".", end="")
    print(s)
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
    ax.plot(sizes, times[:, j], label=f.__name__)


ax.set_xlabel("Array size")
ax.set_ylabel("Time per function call (s)")
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.legend()
ax.grid()
fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thanks for aggregating our different answers and for the cool dataviz. Much appreciated.

Comment: @0x0fba :) I was actually surprised that `zip` stays faster than the other approaches for even large arrays, so I pivoted my answer to include timing results. Maybe the lack of apeed has something to do with creating new objects (such as the df in my answer or the stacked array in yours) taking longer than just getting on with the job. I find it slightly unbelievable that the `numba` solution isn't faster after compilation.

Comment: `dict` is a fundamental python object.  It has to be created one at a time.  You can't "compile" your way around that.

Comment: @hpaulj ah, that would explain why it isn't faster than `zip`! I haven't done much work with numba, but I'm still surprised it isn't _as fast_ as `zip`.

Comment: `numpy` arrays are iterated slower than `list` equivalent. You definitely need to call `zip` on `(a.tolist(), b.tolist())` instead of `(a, b)`

Answer (score 1):

I would say your current approach is fairly efficient. Not knowing any other details, you may be able to precompile w/ numba and save a little execution time. Making some order of magnitude and memory availability assumptions, see below Jupyter cells.

```
# %%
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# %%
x = np.array(range(1,1000000,1))
y = np.array(range(10,1000000,10))
test = [{"a": a_el, "b": b_el} for a_el, b_el in zip(x, y)]

# %%
@jit
def f():
    a = np.array(range(1,1000000,1))
    b = np.array(range(10,1000000,10))
    return [{"a": a_el, "b": b_el} for a_el, b_el in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one-liner that uses a list-comprehension to build the list of dicts, as well as the numpy `column_stack()` method.

```py
res = [{"a": a, "b": b} for a, b in np.column_stack((a,b))]
```